# Which one is correct here: "let alone feed her children" or "leave alone her children"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

The following sentence is from the [BBC web site](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-61239732). It is about violence against women in India.

> "....There is no support system, few shelter homes and the compensation awarded to abandoned women is a pittance - often in the range of 500 to 1500 rupees, which is not enough for a woman to survive, leave alone feed her children."

The expression **"....leave alone her children...."** draws my attention, because I think it should be **"...let alone feed her children".** Since it was written on BBC web site, I needed to double check.

I checked the dictionaries, yes there is a phrase "leave/let someone alone", but it means something different.

Am I right in thinking that it should be **"...let alone feed her children".** in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words are in quotation marks, and are the actual words spoken by a gender activist Madhavi Kuckreja, who is Indian.

You are correct in thinking that 'let alone' is more usual in UK and American English. Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage says, however, that “leave alone” is occasionally seen in British English, where it "seems to be only a rather rare variant.". This may be because it is old-fashioned. Many usages which are old-fashioned or now rare in British English persist in Indian English.

> ...leave alone the fact that she had gone through 'the worst shock of her
> life'.  (Times of India)
>
> Leave alone the fact that the government has made little provision for
> shelter, migrants say they are running out of food (Indian Express)